# tag synonym request: [random] and [random-numbers]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

There is a significant overlap in the tags [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) and [random-numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-numbers).  There are 33 questions tagged [random-numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-numbers) and 41 tagged [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random).  Of these, 11 of them have [both tags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-numbers+random).

Please make [random-numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-numbers) a synonym of [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random).  I make this call of which way based on that many questions tagged with [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) are titled in a way that suggests the author picked the first random tag that showed up (e.g. "How can I create a set of random numbers based on a total and number of objects?" is tagged "random" and "c#").

Looking throughout the list of questions tagged [random-numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-numbers), I could make the argument that they could all be properly tagged with [random](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) (and as I pointed out initially, 1/3 of them are).

Thus: **please make random-numbers a synonym of random**

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]? I just checked - synonyms page says it's done: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/random/synonyms